Maven shade plugin does not exclude META-INF.versions files
Using Maven Shade plugin 3.6.0
I have the following filter:
                    <filters>
                        <filter>
                            <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>module-info.class</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/LICENSE</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/NOTICE</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF.versions.9.module-info</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </filter>
                    </filters>

However, I continue to see the following warning:
classgraph-4.8.160.jar, jackson-core-2.17.0.jar, jackson-databind-2.15.2.jar, jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.15.2.jar, jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.15.2.jar, jackson-module-parameter-names-2.15.2.jar define 1 overlapping classes:
[WARNING]   - META-INF.versions.9.module-info
This is benign, but I'd still like to get rid of the warning if possible. What am I doing wrong?

Your exclude for versions is wrong... META-INF/versions/** check (https://openjdk.org/jeps/238)

Thank you @khmarbaise, that worked. If you want to post this as the answer, I'll accept it.

The used filter is used wrong.
 <filters>
   <filter>
     <artifact>*:*</artifact>
     <excludes>
       <exclude>module-info.class</exclude>
       <exclude>META-INF/LICENSE</exclude>
       <exclude>META-INF/NOTICE</exclude>
       <exclude>META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</exclude>
       <exclude>META-INF/versions/9/module-info.class</exclude>
     </excludes>
   </filter>
 </filters>

or to make that exclude all kind of module-info.class files for multi release jars:
 <filters>
   <filter>
     <artifact>*:*</artifact>
     <excludes>
       <exclude>module-info.class</exclude>
       <exclude>META-INF/LICENSE</exclude>
       <exclude>META-INF/NOTICE</exclude>
       <exclude>META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</exclude>
       <exclude>META-INF/versions/**/module-info.class</exclude>
     </excludes>
   </filter>
 </filters>

